# Use Taylor’s Theorem to approximate $\sqrt{e}$ to within an error of magnitude at most $10^{-6}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Could you please let me know if the following considered as a correct answer to this question.

Taylor Series
$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}x_{0}}{k!}(x - x_{0})^{k}+ \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x - x_{0})^{(n+1)}$.

Take $f(x) = e^x$ and $x_{0} = 0$.

$f^{(0)}(x) = e^x \Rightarrow f^{(0)}(0) = 1$

$f^{(1)}(x) = e^x \Rightarrow f^{(1)}(0) = 1$

$f(x) = e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + .. +  \frac{e ^{c} x^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}$

Now, we take $x = \frac{1}{2}$

$e^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{(2^2)2!} + \frac{1}{(2^3)3!} + .. +  \frac{e ^{c}}{(2^{(n+1)})(n+1)!}$

For any n, the error term equals $E_{n} = \frac{e ^{c}}{(2^{(n+1)})(n+1)!}$ but $c$ is between $x$ and $x_{0}$, i.e., $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ which means $e^c \le e^{\frac{1}{2}} \le \sqrt{3}$

$E_{n} \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{(2^{(n+1)})(n+1)!}$

For $n = 6$, $E_{6} \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{46,080} = 3.76 \left( 10^{-5} \right)$. Then to have an error of magnitude at most $10^{-6}$, we should use $n = 7$?

Comment: Have you calculated $E_7$ to check?

Comment: Incidentally, be aware that "Find an $n$ for which the error is less than $10^{-6}$." is a very different problem than "What is the smallest $n$ for which the error is less than $10^{-6}$?" Make sure you know which of these two problems you actually want an answer to.

Comment: Since the question says "at most $10^{-6}$", I guess, I should be looking for the second question, right?

Comment: I think you need actually to compute the estimate as well as checking the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E_7  \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2^8 \cdot 8!} \approx 1.67803161 \times 10^{-7} < 10^{-6}$$

$n=7$ suffices.

Note that Showing $n =6$ is not sufficient doesn't imply that $n=7 $ is sufficient, we still have to verify that it works.

[Code](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_e0USzva05z_0.py) to check that $n=7$ is indeed the smallest number of terms required.

Comment: Thank you @Siong-Thye-Goh. By showing that for n = 7, $E_7 < 10^{-6}$, does the answer becomes correct and complete?

Comment: The question just asked for a Taylor approximation such that the error terms has magnitude less than $10^[-6}$. It doesn't seems to ask for the smallest $n$ required. If you want to show that $n$ is the smallest term required, then you still have to show that $E_6 > 10^{-6}$.